# How to fill color in ggridges based on height aesthetics?

Tags: r, ggridges

I am trying to create **ggridges** plot with Covid19 Cases counts for various **States**. I would like to **fill** the **color** based on **Cases counts** & Not based on **States** but unable to do so.

I have attempted below code so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ggridges)


df_ind_stacked_daily <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_ind_stacked_daily.csv")) %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date))
```

**working code**:

```
df_ind_stacked_daily %>%
  filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
         State.UnionTerritory != "India") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = State.UnionTerritory,
             height = Daily_cases_counts, group = State.UnionTerritory)) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity", alpha = .8,) + # , scale = 2
  
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_ridges(grid = FALSE)
```

[image]

**Issue:** When I try to **fill color** based on **height** aesthetics then its not working

```
df_ind_stacked_daily %>%
  filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
         State.UnionTerritory != "India") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = State.UnionTerritory, fill = Daily_cases_counts,
             height = Daily_cases_counts, group = State.UnionTerritory)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(stat = "identity", scale = 2, rel_min_height = 0.01, gradient_lwd = 1.) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_ridges(grid = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the value you used for `rel_min_height`. Not sure what's the reason but you could make your code work by reducing the value of `rel_min_height` to e.g. `0.001` or making use of the default value of `0` as I do below:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

df_ind_stacked_daily %>%
  filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
         State.UnionTerritory != "India") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = State.UnionTerritory, fill = Daily_cases_counts,
             height = Daily_cases_counts, group = State.UnionTerritory)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(stat = "identity", scale = 2, gradient_lwd = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_ridges(grid = FALSE) +
  #theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(fill = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @stefan, I am trying `ggridges` for first time & was trying the code from the examples available on blogs & tired to modify with height and in process didn't realize that `rel_min_height` could be the issue. Appreciate your help !!